# html5 audio in chrome playing and seeking

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-audio

I have an audio tag in my page like this:

```
audioPlayerHolder.setHtml('<audio controls="controls" autoplay preload="auto">  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.  <source src="' + key + '&t=ogg" type="audio/ogg"><source src="' + key + '&t=mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>');
```

It works fine in firefox, opera, IE
It works fine chrome or chromium when file duration is less then 1-2 minutes.
It don't work in chrome or chromium when duration is more then 1-2 minutes.
Chrome plays file several seconds and then scroll to the end and stops.

I see that problem begin when chrome try to use partial content request.

I set up php script that correctly response as I think to partial content requests, but problem remains.

This is requests and responses:

1.1

```
GET /php/getsound.php?fn=5c&foo=uvoxm&t=ogg HTTP/1.1
Host: ******
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: https://******/
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: PHPSESSID=gbb1quhuio31v544urdar26fb1
X-Compress: null
Range: bytes=0-
```

1.2

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Tue, 18 Jul 2017 10:33:07 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 599279
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 0-599278/599279
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=sound.ogg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 2020 08:52:00 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
```

2.1

```
GET /php/getsound.php?fn=5c&foo=uvoxm&t=ogg HTTP/1.1
Host: ******
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: https://******/
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: PHPSESSID=gbb1quhuio31v544urdar26fb1
X-Compress: null
Range: bytes=524288-
```

2.2

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Tue, 18 Jul 2017 10:33:08 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 74991
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 524288-599278/599279
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=sound.ogg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 2020 08:52:00 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
```

3.1

```
GET /php/getsound.php?fn=5c&foo=uvoxm&t=ogg HTTP/1.1
Host: ******
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: https://******/
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: PHPSESSID=gbb1quhuio31v544urdar26fb1
X-Compress: null
Range: bytes=32768-
```

3.2

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Tue, 18 Jul 2017 10:33:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 566511
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 32768-599278/599279
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=sound.ogg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 2020 08:52:00 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
```

I think, the problem is in my server-side php script, that sends wrong headers, but can't find what's wrong.

Comment: did you get a response to this? I'm having the same issue - chrome plays the audio file for 90 seconds and stops